# How to Create subjects table that includes multiple teachers and multiple classes

Tags: sql

My condition is like this:
There's a teachers table:Id, name and classes table:Id, name.
I want to create a third table which is subjects table.
I want to figure out columns for the subjects table, where
1)one teacher can teach multiple subjects.
2)and one subject is taught to a multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need multiple tables, it has to have multiple to multiple relations like this. You can even have multiple teachers in the same course or subject.

[image: er diagram]